# Latin for "kitty"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, word-request

Reading "Salve feles" recently, and thinking that this actually meant "Hello cat" -- and not, as I assumed it was intended to, "Hello kitty" -- I began wondering how we could say something like "kitty" in Latin, i.e., a cute, small or young cat, a kitten.

Now, we do have the diminutive *catulus*. It's a young animal, a whelp. It is not specific to cats, and Lewis & Short give an [impressive list](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcatulus1) of animals it has been used for. By itself, it often stands for a young dog, a puppy. So that does not look like a good fit to me. Smith & Hall suggest [*catulus felinus*](https://latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries/?t=sh14433) for "kitten," but this is hardly a very endearing expression.

With that in mind, are there any suggestions of how I could say "What a sweet kitty," or indeed "Hello Kitty"?

What do you think of *felulus (-a)*? E.g. *Euge, felula quam pulchella!* I have not found a single occurrence with Google, but it should be understandable enough.

Comment: Maybe *felecula* on the (non-Classical) analogy of *moles : molecula*?

Comment: Ah let me introduce you to a very cute [video](https://youtu.be/8hq0LCHGcQE) where I heard of the word kitty the first time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option would be *cattulus,* from *[cattus](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/cattus)* (also spelled *[catus](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/catus)*). The *Dictionary of Medieval Latin from British Sources* has an entry for *cattulus*:

> murelegus, cātus, cătulus [*gl.: chytte*], ‥ hic ~us, *a kytylyng* WW.

([Logeion](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/cattulus))

I'm not quite sure how to interpret the ~, but I think the spelling in the original source was actually "catulus", and "cattulus" is an editorial normalization. At least, "catulus" is how it appears in [other documents I have seen](https://books.google.com/books?id=NXoKAAAAIAAJ&pg=RA3-PA219-IA10&lpg=RA3-PA219-IA10&dq=%22a+kytylyng%22&source=bl&ots=aqz8Sp_Aoz&sig=ACfU3U3WF3d9ylBCdzbVNMc-YTRN1BDU5Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjNj_O06qz8AhVYNEQIHc8bB1UQ6AF6BAgKEAM#v=onepage&q=%22a%20kytylyng%22&f=false). It looks like WW [stands for](http://www.dmlbs.ox.ac.uk/web/dmlbs%20bibliography.html) "Anglo-Saxon and Old English Vocabularies".

Going in reverse, by searching the word "kytylyng" online I found several alternative Latin-Middle English glosses that can be seen at the [Middle English Compendium](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED24200/track?counter=2&search_id=5074010) ( University of Michigan), such as *catillus, catunculus, catellus, catulaster.* I imagine that these also might be normalized if used by a modern writer to the forms *cattillus, cattunculus, cattellus, cattulaster.*

As you can see from these, in practice many different kinds of diminutives can be formed in Latin.

However, according to the most typical or "regular" patterns, as described in *[The Formation of Latin
Diminutives of Nouns and Adjectives](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323534846_The_Formation_of_Latin_Diminutives_of_Nouns_and_Adjectives)* by Ian Andreas Miller,  *fēlēs/fēlis* would be expected to produce not *fēlula,* but *fēlēcula* or *fēlicula* (§VII. "Mixed I-Stems: Parisyllables with Nom. Sg. in -ĒS").

I have not found any diminutive of *fēlēs/fēlis* listed in any dictionary or attested in any historical document. *Fēlēcula* occurs in a modern Latin blog *Mema Interretialia* "Internet Memes in Latin" ("[Adorabilis felecula! Adorable kitten!](https://interretialia.tumblr.com/post/32235574600/adorabilis-felecula-adorable-kitten)") (September 24, 2012). The same author previously made a blog post that considered the options *fēlicula, cattulus, cattula* ("[Quomodo "Kitten" Latine Dicitur?](https://diaphanus.livejournal.com/149932.html)", *Diaphanitas,* Feb. 24th, 2006). See also the Latin Discussion forum thread [Kitten](https://latindiscussion.org/threads/kitten.3171/) (Dec 11, 2007).